# highlight-changes-mode: clear displayed changes after saving

Tags: hooks, minor-mode

I currently use this mode like so :

```
(global-highlight-changes-mode t)
(setq highlight-changes-visibility-initial-state nil); initially hide
;; toggle visibility
(global-set-key (kbd "<f2> =")      'highlight-changes-visible-mode)
```

Now, when I save a buffer I would like to stop tracking old changes that I just saved, so that the mode only highlights changes that are not yet written on disk.

What I manually do to solve this is to go to the unsaved buffer, save it, then call `highlight-changes-mode` twice, which works.

Now I'm trying to do that automatically, like this:

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook
          (lambda()
            (interactive)
            (highlight-changes-mode)
            (highlight-changes-mode)))
```

and

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'highlight-changes-mode 'highlight-changes-mode)
```

But it's not working: it just toggles the visibility of the changes.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: This might be a duplicate - it's about toggling a minor mode.

Comment: doc says "If called from Lisp, toggle the mode if ARG is ‘toggle’.  Enable the
mode if ARG is nil, omitted, or is a positive number.  Disable the
mode if ARG is a negative number." . I try `after-save-hook ((highlight-changes-mode -1)(highlight-changes-mode 1))` and it told me `invalid function`. I obviously don't know what I'm doing, please help.

Comment: how can i bump or refresh an unanswered question?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking, but from your comments, maybe this is what you're looking for:

```lisp
(add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda () (highlight-changes-mode 'toggle)))
```

If so, please edit your question to make clear that it's about not understanding how to add a hook function that toggles a minor mode.

And it's nearly always better to use a named function on a hook, instead of an anonymous function:

```lisp
(defun my-toggle-highlight-changes-mode () (highlight-changes-mode 'toggle))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'my-toggle-highlight-changes-mode)
```